# Angular $route.reload() not reloading controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-route-segment

I am trying to reload a route from my controller using $route.reload() but nothing is happening. Here's my controller:

```
 app.controller("FooController", function($scope, data, $route) {
    $scope.model = data.model;
    $scope.meta = data.meta;
    $scope.reload = function() {
      return $route.reload();
    };
  });
```

I'm using [angular-route-segment](http://angular-route-segment.com/) for my routes and the associated route looks like this:

```
 app.config(function($routeSegmentProvider) {
    $routeSegmentProvider.segment("foo", {
      templateUrl: templatesRoot + "/tickers/oldest.html",
      controller: "FooController",
      resolve: {
        data: function($http) {
          return $http.get("/api/foos").then(function(response) {
            return {
              model: response.data.foos,
              meta: response.data.meta
            };
          });
        }
      },
      untilResolved: {
        templateUrl: templatesRoot + "/loading.html"
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `$routeSegment` instead of `$route`.

The property `chain` is an array of segments splitted by each level separately and each element will have a `reload` method.

For example:

```
$scope.reload = function() {
  $routeSegment.chain[0].reload();
};
```

Other properties and methods available on `$routeSegment` and the elements in the `chain` array can be found [here](https://github.com/artch/angular-route-segment#user-content-routesegment-properties).

Comment: Thanks I'd ended up doing this, but reloading the last in the chain array like this: $routeSegment.chain[$routeSegment.chain.length - 1].reload()